# Let $\Gamma = \{\exists x \forall y (x\mathrel R y),\exists x \forall y(y\mathrel R x),\forall x\exists y(x\mathrel R y)\}$. Is $\Gamma$ consistent?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Consider the language consisting of one symbol $R$ for a binary relation. Let $\Gamma = \{\exists x \forall y (x\mathrel R y),\exists x \forall y(y\mathrel R x),\forall x\exists y(x\mathrel R y)\}$. Is $\Gamma$ consistent?

I know that $\Gamma$ is consistent if and only if it has a model. So I believe my task is to find a model that these sentences are satisfied by. Is the natural numbers together with the less than or equal to relation a valid model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about $R$ being a partial order, then these mean:

1. $\exists x\forall y(x\mathrel R y)$, there is a minimum.
2. $\exists x\forall y(y\mathrel R x)$, there is a maximum.
3. $\forall x\exists y(x\mathrel R y)$, every element is related to someone.

Of course, if you want $R$ to be a partial order, then for $x$ being the maximum element the only $y$ such that $x\mathrel R y$ can be true is $x=y$. But partial orders are reflexive. So that's not a problem.

Does the natural numbers have a maximum?

> What is the simplest partial order which has a minimum and maximum? (recall, these need not be distinct!)

Comment: It doesn't have a maximum, so if I'm following correctly I could take a finite subset of the natural numbers for instance- say {1,2} and equip it with the less than or equal to relations and then the sentences hold using your interpretation. So gamma is consistent Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** There is not a single negation symbol to be seen in $\Gamma$.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: I meant to hint that none of the sentence in $\Gamma$ can possibly be false due to $R$ not holding for some pair. The other answer does spell that out much more explicitly than I was going to.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\{a\}$ and $R = \{(a,a)\}$. $(A, R)$ is model for $\Gamma$. Hence $\Gamma$ is consistent.